# JAXBException unexpected element

Tags: xml, jaxb

I am using client web service.
1.Making a WS request and getting a response in a XML formate.
2. Using client WSDL, I have generated stubs, Hence using the same to UnMarshall the XML to POJO.

the response is as below :

```
<ns2:outputParams>

            <ns2:param>
               <ns2:name>response</ns2:name>
               </ns2:param>
                  <ns2:artifactDefinitionvalue><![CDATA[<elements xmlns="http://www.model.bll.nfv.activator.ov.hp.com">
 <artifactInstances>
    <artifactInstance>
      ... Some more tags 
     </artifactInstance>
 </artifactInstances>
</elements>]]>
</ns2:value>


     </ns2:outputParams>
```

Now when I am unmarshalling the XML using artifactInstances.Class, I am getting error JAXBException 
         unexpected element (uri:"http://www.model.bll.nfv.activator.ov.hp.com", local:"elements").

It seems "element" tag is extra, but I dont have JAXB stub for that, it is been added in the response.

Please help to resolve.
Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Actually It was mistake on my part and I feel bad for the same.
The does have an stub/class for "Element", so I can unmarshall using the same,since this "Element" is "XMLRoolElement".

Thanks